# Detecting an empty flat file with SSIS script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, script-task

I am looking for a script task which identifies a zero KB file in a folder and outputs the same in a mail or text file.

Thanks in advance. Let me know for any questions.

Comment: Did you read what the purpose of SO is? You're supposed to be asking programming related questions, not that someone provides you scripts or something else. Your previous "questions" are also asking for ready made scripts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is just asking someone to do work for him.

Comment: If you need a script written, hire a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();

String strContents;
StreamReader sReader;
sReader = File.OpenText(FilePath);
strContents = sReader.ReadToEnd();
sReader.Close();
if (strContents.Length==0)
    MessageBox.Show("Empty file");
```

Comment: Looks like this is to read one file but I am looking for all the files that loops through in a folder and get the output. It will be much appreciated if I can get that script :)

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/